# jQuery ajax post failing, but proper data returned

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Scratching my head on this one.  I'm trying to do a simple ajax form post, and the response I'm getting is an error.  However, my page still displays my JSON string as the response.  Here is my javascript chunk:

```
$(function () {
    $('#searchForm').submit(function () {
        var jqhxr = $.post({ url: this.action, type: this.method, data: $(this).serialize(), dataType: 'json' })
                     .done(function () { alert('success') })
                     .fail(function () { alert('fail') })
                     .always(function () { alert('complete') });
        return false;
    });
});
```

This is posting to an ASP.NET MVC page (although I don't think that is the problem); the route is correct, gets hit in the debugger and returns the proper data, but just in case:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Search(SearchFormViewModel vm)
    {
        var products = _productRepo.Find(...);
        return Json(products);
    }
```

So, what happens is that the form is submitted via ajax as it is supposed to be, I get the 'fail' alert box, but the JSON string still displays, so the request was successful.  Any ideas?

Comment: When you say the JSON string still displays, displays where? None of your callbacks output the data from the response.

Comment: Try returning something like Json(new {test = "ok"}); and see if it still will alert fail.

Comment: should .done be .success by any chance? I've actually never played with done and have no sandbox to set it up.  If you hook it up with firebug and you can see the data coming back properly, then try this route.  I'd assume the designers would consider done a callback that happens AFTER the success or fail methods have executed.  Looking into the docs now.

Comment: What is the method of the form. Is it GET by chance? That would cause it to fail

Comment: (@ steve_c)  The JSON string actually just renders in the browser, which isn't what I want to happen, I want to do something else with it (bind it to a Telerik MVC grid, actually), but it was my intention to do that within the "success:" function, which isn't getting hit at all, hence my question.  Going to try Jeff Ancel's suggestion below.

Answer (score 1):

This is a stab in the dark really, but I wonder if this would do what you want it to do.

```
   $(function () {
        var jqhxr;     
        $('#searchForm').submit(function () {
            jqhxr = $.post({ url: this.action, 
                                type: this.method, 
                                data: $(this).serialize(), 
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success: function(data){ alert("success - data"); }
                        });                         
            jqhxr.done(function () { alert('success - done') });
            jqhxr.fail(function () { alert('fail') });
            jqhxr.always(function () { alert('complete') });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Essentially, all I did here was gave it a success outlet.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff.  Unfortunately that did not work, as I still only get the "fail" alert box.  The .done, .fail, .always methods is how jQuery suggests these calls be done now.  Should be in the documentation somewhere, I didn't think to bookmark it.

Comment: Yeah, I went and looked at the latest docs and saw that it did have those methods, but there is also the "success" function, so I figured it'd be worth a try.

Comment: Do you have firebug, can you get your information back in the console?  I did a small edit above to match the docs.  Also recommend checking out the "GET" versus "POST" suggestion by Keith above.

Comment: This code looks flawed ... the `jqxhr` methods need to be inside the handler, because jqxhr isn't initialized until `submit`.

Comment: I agree, good catch.  Modified the answer for @Scott Rippey's suggestion here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the answer in this blog post:  http://blog.janjonas.net/2011-08-07/asp_net-mvc_3-jquery-ajax-submit-ajax-form-supporting-unobtrusive-client-side-validation-and-server-side-validation.

The only differences were the use of $('#searchForm').live('submit', function(e) { ... }); as well as the use of e.preventDefault();, which I think was the key here.  I wasn't preventing the default behavior, which was why I was seeing the JSON result in the browser itself.  Doesn't explain why I was getting the "fail" alert, but I'm now getting the "success" alert.  So I'm posting this as the answer as it contains a link to the information that solved the issue.  Hope this helps people in the future!

Comment: I should also add that Scott Rippey's comment about the jqhxr variable not being initialized until the submit function was also likely an issue and was helpful in resolving this, so I'm going to upvote his comment.  Thanks, Scott!

Comment: Oh, I'm surprised no one caught that!  You always need to `e.PreventDefault()` (or return `false`) for your submit events!

Comment: The reason you get the `fail` alert is simple - when a XHR is in progress, and the user navigates away from the page, the XHR is cancelled and immediately fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `$.post` with `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({    
    url: this.action, 
    type: this.method, 
    data: $(this).serialize(), 
    dataType: 'json' }
)
.done(function () { alert('success') })
.fail(function () { alert('fail') })
.always(function () { alert('complete') });
```